# How to get only CHANGED data from Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics API to get the number of page views for each page of my website. In order to reduce the number of api calls, I'm setting an interval for doing this and cache the data on my server. For each api call, I try to get the page views of every page on my site and update them to my database.

Is there a way to get only CHANGED DATA from a specific time stamp? For example, only page views that changed within last 2 hours.

I think it would be a kind of filters (if any) but I could not find it from the documentation here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Answer (score 0):

You could add a filter for ga:dateHour so that it comes back in the last two hours.   But the problem is that it takes Google around 4 hours to process the data.  So you wouldn't get anything back for two hours ago.

If you want to see data that is that new you have to use the Realtime api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

What exactly is your query currently?  If you do ga:date, ga:dateHour, ga:pagepath, ga:pageviews The results will all be returned in one query (not counting next pages), thats a log way to the 10,000 queries per day limit.

On a side note.  What do you mean by changed? Nothing is going to change in data previously processed.

Comment: My query is to get ga:pageviews based on ga:pagepath. As my site has thousands of pages and still growing, I don't want to get and update the pageviews of every page but only pagepath whose pageviews has changed since my last query executed.    
The use of ga:dateHour just helps return the pageviews in that time slot. Moreover, it is a dimension so I can't use >= operator on it.